# Excel macro checks if there is formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, worksheet-function

I want to make a macro that checks if that cell get its value from a formula. I cann't find anything similar. Any tips??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [HasFormula](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837123.aspx) function to determine if a Range has a cell with a formula.

Answer (score 1):

NamedRange.HasFormula Property should be what you need.

FYR MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.hasformula(v=vs.80).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1